# Cannot See Entire GridView

Tags: android

I have a string `Canada@3@United States@14@Zambia@3@` I need to show this on a gridView.

```
String[] numbers=newString.split("\\@");
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});


<GridView
   android:id="@+id/gridView1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
   android:numColumns="2"
   android:textColor="#151B54" >
</GridView>
```

I am able to see only the first entry also in White color(OnItemClickListener) is working for me, I can see that in form of toast only.Please correct me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did add the Adapter so, the view was not being shown.